# Lua function to delete files with specific extention or pattern

Tags: lua

Is there any function to remove files in a directory certain extension or pattern?

For example, to delete all bbram extension files in nvmdir directory.

```
os.remove(nvmdir .. "\\*.bbram")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in function for this. You can use the shell, as in

`os.execute("rm " .. nvmdir .. "/*.bbram")`

Comment: Beware that this is subject to injection, so can be a dangerous code.